# Unable to do administrative tasks/install packages

Tags: 10.10, permissions, users

I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 using Wubi, but it doesn't seem that I have proper priveleges or something to install software or do other administrative tasks.

[image: Example 1.] 
[image: Example 2.]

If anyone has any suggestions, tips, or tricks, they would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a fresh install? Can you apply a simple sudo process? ie. `sudo fdisk -l` ?

Comment: Yes, fresh install. I will try the sudo command though.

Comment: The results of it were this:                                 Disk /dev/sda: 164.7 GB, 164696555520 bytes
240 heads, 63 sectors/track, 21274 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 15120 * 512 = 7741440 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00063b97

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       21275   160833536    7  HPFS/NTFS

Comment: So it seems a PolicyKit problem, sudo works Ok

Comment: Yeah, seems like a policykit problem. I could'nt find any recent 10.10 bug about that. 10.10's support ends by 2012.04, so maybe you can try a more recent Ubuntu version @Jake.

Comment: can you invoke sudo usermod -a -G admin jake in a terminal? This adds you to the group "admin". Does it work after that?

Comment: Well, I updated to a newer version, that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thes question was answered by the OP in the comments

> updated to a newer version, that fixed the problem